# TCL namespace and source

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I have two files: main.tcl and paths.tcl.
main.tcl:

```
set p "paths.tcl"
puts $p
if {[lindex $argv 0]} {
    source $::p
    puts $::techDir
}
namespace eval ::newWkSpace {
    source $::p
}
puts $::newWkSpace::techDir
```

paths.tcl:

```
set techDir ../tech
```

And I do two trials:

```
$ tclsh main.tcl 0
paths.tcl
../tech
$ tclsh main.tcl 1
paths.tcl
../tech
can't read "::newWkSpace::techDir": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $::newWkSpace::techDir"
    (file "main.tcl" line 11)
```

Can someone explain the error, and why it does not happen in the first trial ? (that's with tcl 8.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that in your second test case, when the interetter executed

```
namespace eval ::newWkSpace {
    source $::p
}
```

and came to execute

```
set techDir ../tech
```

it noticed that ::techDir existed, it assigned into that and didn't bother the create a techDir variable in the newWkSpace namespace.

A question that arises is, "Why are you doing this?". If you really want to get it working, try putting a `variable techDir` statement in your namespace before you source paths.tcl, thus:

```
namespace eval newWkSpace {
    variable techDir;   #<<<<<<<<<<<
    source $::p
}
```

I expect that someone who *really* understands Tcl will be along in a while to put me right and give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this is helpful, now it works :-) I do that because I have a lot of paths declared in files like paths.tcl and at some point I need to have access to the paths declared in two different files (but I would like to avoid to modify all those files).

Comment: Using `variable` there is highly recommended or you can end up with weird global namespace shadowing effects. This has been the cause of mysterious bugs in Tcl itself in the past…